# How to explain the parametric hyperbolic plot?

Tags: calculus

The parametric equation is given as:
$$\begin{cases}x={t^2+1 \over t^2-1}\\y={2t \over t^2-1}\end{cases}$$
and we know it is this hyperbolic equation:$$(x^2-y^2)=1$$
We can see that when $y=0$, $x\pm1$. But from the parametric equation, I can only see that when $t=0$, we have $y=0$, and $x=-1$. Where is the $x=+1$ point? How to plot this equation for both sides of $x$?

[The original question is here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135557/converting-from-parametric-to-cartesian/1135604#1135604)

Comment: If you rotate the rectangular hyper bola $xy=1$ by $45^{\circ}$ with respect to the origin, you get your hyperbola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hyperbola has two pieces (often called "branches"). The implicit equation $x^2 - y^2=1$ describes both of these pieces -- the points on both pieces satisfy the equation.

But the parametric equation represents only a portion of the curve, with the point $(1,0)$ missing.

To understand the situation, let's see how the point $P(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ moves along the curve as $t$ increases from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. For convenience, I'll refer to the four quadrants as NE, NW, SW, and SE. The NE quadrant is where $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$, and so on. Here's a (not very accurate) picture:

[image: hyperbola]

And here's the story in words:

- When $t$ is close to $-\infty$, $P(t)$ is in the SE quadrant, just below the point $(1,0)$
- As $t$ approaches $-1$, $P(t)$ moves rapidly to the SE, going to infinity along the asymptote $y=-x$
- When $t$ is slightly larger than $-1$, $P(t)$ is far away in the NW quadrant, again near the asymptote $y=-x$
- As $t$ increases from $-1$ to $1$, $P(t)$ moves down the left branch of the curve, passing from the NW quadrant into the SW one when $t=0$
- When $t$ is slightly larger than $1$, $P(t)$ is far away in the NE quadrant, near the asymptote $y=x$
- As $t$ increases, $P(t)$ moves down the curve in the NE quadrant. It approaches the point $(1,0)$ but never gets there for finite values of $t$.

This situation often occurs -- the set of points represented by parametric equations is often just a subset of the set of points represented by an implicit equation. In particular, parametric equations (that use continuous functions) can only represent "connected" curves, not curves that have several disconnected pieces. Another example is $y^2 = 1$. This represents the two horizontal lines $y=1$ and $y=-1$. The parametric equations $(x,y) = (t,1)$ represent the line $y=1$, and the parametric equations $(x,y) = (t,-1)$ represent the line $y=-1$, but no parametric equation could represent both of these lines simultaneously.

Another common example: the parametric equations
$$
x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \quad ; \quad y = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$
represent most of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, but the point $(-1,0)$ is missing.

Comment: he did get $x=-1$

Comment: Can you provide an example for $y^2=1$ in parametric?

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 3):

> *Where is the $x=+1$ point ?*

At infinity. Just let $t\to\infty$, and evaluate the two limits.

Comment: It is good. I think the $t=\pm 1$ is the key.

Comment: Or let $t \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

for $(x,y)\rightarrow t$
    $$(x,-y)\rightarrow -t$$
     $$(-x,-y)\rightarrow \frac{1}{t}$$
     $$(-x,y)\rightarrow \frac{1}{-t}$$
now you can get every point so you can see to get $x=1$ the parameter should tend to infinity

Comment: I voted +1, but I would like to say, this one is exhaustive.

Comment: yes you are right ,

Comment: i changed my answer this is right according to me, my first one was wrong @PdotWang